# Diasporan Neta Revai in Temple times

Tags: orla-revai

If Orlah is observed outside of Israel and the Beit HaMikdash would be standing, what is done with Neta Revay, fourth year fruit?

Answer (score 2):

There are two questions here: Is there Neta Revai outside of Eretz Yisroel like Orlah; and, if there is, can the Revai be brought to Yerushalaim to be eaten when the Beis Hamikdash is standing.

The first question is addressed directly in [Shulchan Aruch (Yore deya 294:7)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.294.7?lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=en):

> דין נטע רבעי נוהג אף בחוצה לארץ ויש מי שאומר שאינו נוהג אלא בארץ אבל בחוצה לארץ פירות הבאים אחר שעברו שני ערלה מותרים בלא פדיון
>
> The law of Neta Revai is practiced even outside of Eretz Yisroel. However, there is one who says that it is not practiced except in the Land, but outside of the Land fruits that are produced after the years of Orlah are over are permitted without redemption.

Therefore, practically, one must redeem the fourth year fruit without a beracha. ([Shach](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.294.7?lang=bi&with=Siftei%20Kohen&lang2=en), [Bear hativ](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.294.7?lang=bi&with=Ba%27er%20Hetev&lang2=en).)

The opinion that there is no Neta Revai outside of Eretz Yisroel is the [Rambam (Maachalos Asuros 10:15)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Forbidden_Foods.10.15?lang=he). He explains his reasoning:

> יֵרָאֶה לִי שֶׁאֵין דִּין נֶטַע רְבָעִי נוֹהֵג בְּחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ אֶלָּא אוֹכֵל פֵּרוֹת שָׁנָה רְבִיעִית בְּלֹא פִּדְיוֹן כְּלָל שֶׁלֹּא אָמְרוּ אֶלָּא הָעָרְלָה. וְקַל וָחֹמֶר הַדְּבָרִים וּמַה סּוּרְיָא שֶׁהִיא חַיֶּבֶת בְּמַעַשְׂרוֹת וּבִשְׁבִיעִית מִדִּבְרֵיהֶם אֵינָהּ חַיֶּבֶת בְּנֶטַע רְבָעִי כְּמוֹ שֶׁיִּתְבָּאֵר בְּהִלְכוֹת מַעֲשֵׂר שֵׁנִי. חוּצָה לָאָרֶץ לֹא כָּל שֶׁכֵּן שֶׁלֹּא יִהְיֶה נֶטַע רְבָעִי נוֹהֵג בָּהּ. אֲבָל בְּאֶרֶץ יִשְׂרָאֵל נוֹהֵג בָּהּ בֵּין בִּפְנֵי הַבַּיִת בֵּין שֶׁלֹּא בִּפְנֵי הַבַּיִת
>
> ...for they only said Orlah (is practiced outside of the Land). And it is a kal vachomer; if Syria, which has Ma'aser and Shevi'is on a Rabbinic level, doesn't have Neta Revai, as explained in Hilchos Ma'aser Sheni, (places farther) outside of the Land, certainly Neta Revai will not be practiced there. However, in the Land of Israel it is practiced both when the Temple is standing and when the Temple is not standing.

(Still working on this, but for now...)

The next question is, can the Neta Revai be brought to Yerusalaim and eaten according to the opinion that it applies at all. The [Rambam (Ma'aser Sheni 1:14)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Mishneh_Torah%2C_Second_Tithes_and_Fourth_Year%27s_Fruit.1.14?lang=he&with=Commentary&lang2=he) says that it may not be brought to be eaten and may only be redeemed:

> מַעֲשֵׂר שֵׁנִי הוֹאִיל וְטָעוּן הֲבָאַת מָקוֹם אֵין מְבִיאִין אוֹתוֹ מִחוּצָה לָאָרֶץ כִּבְכוֹר בְּהֵמָה. לְפִיכָךְ לֹא חִיְּבוּ לְהַפְרִישׁ מַעֲשֵׂר שֵׁנִי בְּסוּרְיָא. וְיֵרָאֶה לִי שֶׁמַּעֲשֵׂר שֵׁנִי שֶׁמַּפְרִישִׁים בְּאֶרֶץ שִׁנְעָר וּבְמִצְרַיִם פּוֹדִין אוֹתוֹ וּמְבִיאִין דָּמָיו לִירוּשָׁלַיִם. וְכֵן יֵרָאֶה לִי שֶׁלֹּא חִיְּבוּ מְקוֹמוֹת אֵלּוּ בְּמַעֲשֵׂר שֵׁנִי אֶלָּא כְּדֵי לִקְבֹּעַ מַעֲשֵׂר עָנִי כְּדֵי שֶׁיִּהְיוּ עֲנִיֵּי יִשְׂרָאֵל סוֹמְכִים עֲלֵיהֶם:

This is the Rambam according to his reasoning that there is no Maaser in Syria, but the other opinion about Maaser seems to disagree. For example the Raavid there:

> מעשר שני הואיל והוא טעון הבאת מקום כו' עד מעשר שני בסוריא. א''א אין הטעם הזה מספיק דר''ע הוא דס''ל הכי ולא אמר אלא ליקרב אבל לקדש מיהא קדוש והכי איתא בבכורות פ''ב ונ''ל מה שאמרו שאין מעשר שני בסוריא מן התורה קאמר ואם גזרו עליה מעשרות לא גזרו עליה נטע רבעי:
>
> ויראה לי שמע''ש וכו' עד סומכין עליהן. א''א אלו דברי רוח:

Comment: Are you sure revai from chu"l can be taken to Jerusalem and eaten? You can't do that with maaser sheni from chu"l

Comment: The last paragraph is where the interesting question is which you just assume as obvious. We don't bring Maaser Behema from Chul for instance. Is this the same?

Comment: It seems pretty clear the OP was asking according to the opinion that there is Revai in the Diaspora, so I'm not sure most of this post is really necessary.

Comment: @JoelK, interesting. What's your source? Is that because of tumah?

Comment: @Mordechai See the last mishna in challah and bechorot 53

Comment: There is no question about orlah is chutz laaretz, so I  was assuming that there was a real question about the Revai, where there is a machlokes.

Comment: @DoubleAA, that mishna is about bikurim, not ma'aser.

Comment: bikkurim and bechor.... the point is your claim that the diaspora should be the same as israel because the mitzva applies there is non-trivial and you should source it to be convincing.

Comment: @Mordechai Regarding maaser sheni see Rambam Hilchot Maaser Sheni 1:14

Comment: I see. Updating accordingly...